# Wordpress list all users and users with subscription level 1 first

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I want to create a list of users, and show the paying users first in the list - How do I do this? I've tried creating an SQL query, however im struggling a bit on how to make JOINS...

Lets say I have 10 users and 4 of them is paying customers. When in my SQL statement I want to get all users, but the ones that are paying should be listed first?

```
$row = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wptest_users JOIN wptest_usermeta on user.rcp_subscription_level");
```

So what im trying to do there is getting all users from wptest_users, and then trying to make a join with wptest_usermeta, and getting the meta field I want to order by - So if "rcp_subscription_level" equals 1, then the user is a paying customer...

Hope it makes sense on that im trying to achieve, and hope someone can help?

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY rcp_subscriptions_level ASC` (assuming 1 is the lowest value, if 0 is unpiad, `DESC`)

Comment: the problem is that right now im not getting any results.... So looks like im doing it wrong?

Comment: You aren't joining on a column.

Comment: How to I do this? I though that was what im doing where i write: JOIN wptest_usermeta on user.rcp_subscription_level ?

Comment: You need to join on a common column, example: `join wptest_usermeta.column_name on user.relational_column`

Comment: Hmm, not quite sure im doing this correctly ? 

$row = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wptest_users JOIN wptest_usermeta.rcp_subscription_level on user.subscriptionlevel");

   foreach ($row as $row) {
    echo $row->subscriptionlevel;
   }

Comment: Tried this, but still not getting any results: 
SELECT wptest_users.id, wptest_users.display_name FROM wptest_users INNER JOIN wptest_usermeta ON wptest_users.user_url = wptest_usermeta.meta_key

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, almost got it now:

Got this so far:

```
SELECT wptest_users.ID, wptest_users.display_name, wptest_usermeta.user_id, wptest_usermeta.meta_value, wptest_usermeta.meta_key FROM wptest_users, wptest_usermeta WHERE wptest_users.ID = user_id AND meta_key = 'rcp_subscription_level' ORDER by user_id
```

Now I only need to sort it by the value of the subscription level